# Single sum of squares of Clebsch–Gordan coefficients

Tags: lie-groups

Let $C^{j_3 m_3}_{j_1 m_1 j_2 m_2}$ be the standard Clebsch–Gordan coefficients of $\operatorname{SU}(2)$. They obey the orthogonality relation
$$ \sum_{j_3} \sum_{m_3} \left(C^{j_3 m_3}_{j_1 m_1 j_2 (m_3 - m_1)} \right)^2  = 1.$$
My question is about what can be said if I remove the sum over $j_3$. Does there exist a bound for
$$ \max_{j_3} \sum_{m_3} \left(C^{j_3 m_3}_{j_1 m_1 j_2 (m_3 - m_1)} \right)^2 $$
in terms of $m_1$, $j_1$ and $j_2$? Of course it is $\leq 1$, but I am interested in whether this expression decays in $j_1$ and $j_2$, or some combination thereof. Positive or negative statements, or a reference, would be very useful.

Comment: if I'm not mistaken, there is a simple closed-form answer: $$\max_{j_3} \sum_{m_3} \left(C^{j_3 m_3}_{j_1 m_1 j_2 (m_3 - m_1)} \right)^2=\frac{1+2j_1+2j_2}{(1+2j_1)(1+2j_2)},$$ independent of $m_1\in[-j_1,j_1]$. This simple result may well be in the literature, I arrived at it via Mathematica (see the answer box).

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450410/single-sum-of-squares-of-clebsch-gordan-coefficients#comment1164263_450410), the [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/450447).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the sum of [Clebsch–Gordan coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients),$^\ast$
$$J=  \sum_{m_3=-j_3}^{j_3} \left(C^{j_3,m_3}_{j_1, m_1; j_2, (m_3 - m_1)} \right)^2$$
with $2j_1,2j_2,2j_3\in\mathbb{N}$ and $2m_1\in\mathbb{Z}$. For an nonvanishing sum we also need $j_3\in\{|j_1-j_2|,|j_1-j_2|+1,\ldots j_1+j_2-1, j_1+j_2\}$ and $m_1\in\{-j_1,-j_1+1,\ldots,j_1-1, j_1\}$.
With these restrictions the sum is independent of $m_1$, so I may set $m_1=j_1$. The sum also increases monotonically with increasing $j_3$, reaching its maximal value $J_{\rm max}$ for $j_3=j_1+j_2$, hence
$$J_{\rm max}=\sum_{m=-j_2}^{j_2} \left(C^{j_1+j_2,j_1+m}_{j_1, j_1; j_2, m} \right)^2=\sum_{m=-j_2}^{j_2}\frac{\Gamma (2 j_2+1) \Gamma (2 j_1+j_2+m+1)}{(1+2j_2)\Gamma (2 j_1+2 j_2+1) \Gamma (j_2+m+1)}$$
$$\qquad=\frac{1+2j_1+2j_2}{(1+2j_1)(1+2j_2)}.$$

---

<sub>$^\ast$ Mathematica normalizes these coefficients such that $\sum_{j_3}J=1+2j_2$. Here I use the normalization of the OP, where $\sum_{j_3}J=1$.</sub>

Comment: You [mention](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450410/single-sum-of-squares-of-clebsch-gordan-coefficients#comment1164263_450410) that you used Mathematica.  Would you be willing to post the code?  (Or a link to a gist, as I believe you have sometimes done.)

Comment: there is not much code to post, actually; the orthogonality relation is `Sum[(ClebschGordan[{j1, m1}, {j2, m3 - m1}, {j3, m3}])^2, {j3, 
  Abs[j1 - j2], j1 + j2, 1}, {m3, -j3, j3}]` For the evaluation of $J$ I omit the sum over $j_3$.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450410/single-sum-of-squares-of-clebsch-gordan-coefficients/450447#comment1164290_450447), thanks!

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.